# C# how to add a price by clicking the image

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting

I want to make a winform app for small restaurants. If the cashier clicks on a product image, it should add it to the total bill. My problem is that the total bill label should be able to take prices like 122,93€. I tried to make it an int, string, double, or decimal, but I always get formatting errors.

Here is a screenshot of my app.

[image: screenshot of my app.]

Comment: Welcome! Does http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ help? What kind of formatting errors are you getting?

Comment: Store prices in decimal format. When you need to present a price or a total, format the value using the current CultureInfo Currency format, `"C" ` (`[decimal value].ToString("C")`). The `C` format adds the Currency Symbol and also considers the default number of decimal digits in the current Culture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to format a label, then try this `lblBill.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C2");`

This website should also help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings